# PDDL forall effect with durative actions

Tags: forall, pddl

I am both using durative actions and trying to be able to clear a predicate over all elements of a certain type. See below. Is this possible? If so, does anyone know the correct syntax? Thanks!

```lisp
    (:durative-action init
      :parameters (?r - robot)
      :duration ( = ?duration 1)
      :condition (and
             (at start (robot_uninitialized ?r))
             (at start (robot_free ?r))
                 )
      :effect (and
          (at start(not(robot_free ?r)))
          (at end (assign (robot_on_fastener_number_in_sequence) 1))
          (at end (not(robot_uninitialized ?r)))
          (at end (robot_free ?r))
          (at end (forall (?f - fastener) (not(fastener_selected ?f))))
          )
    )
```

I am running the popf planner and the error provided is: `Syntax error in timed effect`.

Comment: At first sight that should work. What error did you encounter, using which planner?
Which `requirements` do you use?

Comment: I am running the popf planner and the error provided is: Syntax error in timed effect. Any durative action example with a forall effect (or precondition) that works would be much appreciated. Even better if it works with popf.

Comment: Which `requirements` do you use?

Comment: `(:requirements :strips :typing :fluents :disjunctive-preconditions :durative-actions :negative-preconditions)`

Comment: I am not sure it will help, but can you try with `:universal-preconditions` or even `:adl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VAL parser indeed shows the `Syntax error in timed effect` error. I tried to invert the order of `at end` and `forall` and it stopped complaining. As popf is using the same parser, it should be happy with that syntax too.

```lisp
  :effect (and
      (forall (?f - fastener) 
          (at end (not (fastener_selected ?f)))
      )
  )
```

But in the condition, VAL accepts the syntax in the opposite order:

```lisp
    :condition (and
        (at end (forall (?f - fastener) 
            (fastener_selected ?f))
        )
    )
```

Full example: http://editor.planning.domains/#read_session=BCBDpV4YQE

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue. Tried to give it a plus, but don't have enough points.

Comment: One more question... is it possible to have a "forall" statement in the conditions clause? Copying the above to the condition causes a syntax error (even without the "not").

Comment: Sure it is. You can find syntax examples here: https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl/domain

Comment: Here is a full example. http://editor.planning.domains/#read_session=BCBDpV4YQE

Interestingly, VAL and Popf accepts the forall condition, but in the opposite order:

```
        (at end (forall (?f - fastener) 
            (fastener_selected ?f))
        )
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot. Strange how the syntax changes between the condition and effect clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The "complete" [PDDL3.1 BNF](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/scommv/IPC-14/repository/kovacs-pddl-3.1-2011.pdf) version that is typically used specifically states that what you are trying is not allowed. However, it is most probably a mistake that got carried over from the original grammar definition, that propagated down to the parser implementations (or maybe vice-versa?)

A durative action effect `<da-effect>` is defined as follows:

```
<da-effect> ::= (and <da-effect>*)
<da-effect> ::= <timed-effect>
<da-effect> ::= (forall (<typed list (variable)>) <da-effect>)
<da-effect> ::= (when <da-GD> <timed-effect>)
```

So you can have a plain `<timed-effect>`, a conjunction of `<da-effect>` or wrap the `<da-effect>` in a `forall` or `when` (if the `:conditional-effects` requirement is supported by the planner.)

So technically you can have nested `forall` too.

`<timed-effect>` is then defined as follows:

```
<timed-effect> ::= (at <time-specifier> <cond-effect>)
<timed-effect> ::= (at <time-specifier> <f-assign-da>)
<timed-effect> ::= (<assign-op-t> <f-head> <f-exp-t>)
```

with `<cond-effect>` defined as:

```
<cond-effect> ::= (and <p-effect>*)
<cond-effect> ::= <p-effect>
```

But `<p-effect>` does not support conditional-effects:

```
<p-effect> ::= (not <atomic formula(term)>)
<p-effect> ::= <atomic formula(term)>
<p-effect> ::= (<assign-op> <f-head> <f-exp>)
<p-effect> ::= (assign <function-term> <term>)
<p-effect> ::= (assign <function-term> undefined)
```

However, interestingly, in the original [PDDL2.1 (Fox and Long, 2003)](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/JAIR/Vol20/JAIR-2002.pdf) definition `<timed-effect>` is defined as follows:

```
<timed-effect> ::= (at <time-specifier> <a-effect>)
<timed-effect> ::= (at <time-specifier> <f-assign-da>)
<timed-effect> ::= (<assign-op-t> <f-head> <f-exp-t>)
```

Now `<a-effect>` is not defined anywhere, and it was probably just a typo, where it mostly likely was supposed to be `<da-effect>`. **In which case, the syntax you are trying would have worked.**

This mistake got carried forward up to PDDL3.1 and *"corrected"* to `<cond-effect>` (presumably instead of `<da-effect>`), which gives rise to your issue.