# PDDL forall with when condition in durative-action

Tags: forall, pddl

This question builds on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522485/pddl-forall-effect-with-durative-actions) about forall clauses. I would like to limit the forall with a 'when' statement as shown below:

```lisp
(:durative-action finish
  :parameters (?r - robot ?p - part)
  :duration ( = ?duration 1)
  :condition (and
      (at start (robot_free ?r))
      (at start (forall (?f - fastener_loc)
                    when (part_fastener ?p ?f)
                     (loc_not_fastened ?f)
                )
      )
     )
  :effect (and
      (at start(not (robot_free ?r)))
      (at end (part_free ?p))
      (at end (robot_free ?r))
     )
)
```

This works without the 'when' statement. When I include the 'when' statement, I receive several errors:

```lisp
Error: Syntax error in durative-action declaration.
Error: Unreadable structure
Error: Syntax error in domain
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work with an imply statement.

```
(:durative-action finish
  :parameters (?r - robot ?p - part)
  :duration ( = ?duration 1)
  :condition (and
      (at start (robot_free ?r))
      (at start (forall (?f - fastener_loc)
                    (imply (part_fastener ?p ?f)(loc_not_fastened ?f))
                )
      )
     )
  :effect (and
      (at start(not (robot_free ?r)))
      (at end (part_free ?p))
      (at end (robot_free ?r))
     )
)
```

Not sure if this could also work the the `when` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `when` clause needs to be wrapped in (brackets)

Comment: Tried bracket just around the ```when``` clause and also around the ```when``` and the following clause. Same error...

Comment: Ah, right. Missed that this was in a `condition` block and not an `effect` one. For the former you only use `imply` and for the latter you only use `when`.

Answer (score 0):

The `when` keyword is restricted to conditional effects.
You can see the definition in the [PDDL3.1 BNF](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/scommv/IPC-14/repository/kovacs-pddl-3.1-2011.pdf).

Be a bit careful when combining `forall` with `imply`, because it could lead to a nasty combinatorial explosion. Keep in mind that `imply` typically gets `flattened` (Negation Normal Form) to a disjunction. So in your case it would become:

`(or (not (part_fastener ?p ?f)) (loc_not_fastened ?f))`

Which planners typically split into two separate actions (to remove disjunctions), one with `(not (part_fastener ?p ?f))` as its precondition, and one with `(loc_not_fastened ?f)`.

The `forall` then explodes this to all pairwise combinations of the disjunction, to ground it to all instances of `fastener_loc`, combined with all grounded combinations of `robot` and `part` action parameters (to generate the grounded actions themselves).

If you only have a few objects of each type I guess you should be OK.